# Gitlab CI/CD artifact gets erased after a job executes

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a 2 stage, 3 job CI workflow.Here is my .yaml file:

```
before_script:
  - $env:PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CMake\\bin;$env:PATH"
  - $env:PATH = "C:\GitLab-Runner\\MinGW\\bin;$env:PATH"
  - $env:PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\myAPP\\bin;$env:PATH"

stages:
  - project_build
  - project_analysis

project_build:
  stage: project_build
  tags:
    - myapp
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
    - cmake --build .
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
    expire_in: 1 days

project_analysis_phase_1:
  stage: project_analysis
  tags:
    - myapp
  script:
    - mkdir my_application
    - myapp -prog "gitlab_demo" -author "xxxxx" -output-project "my_application/my_project" -output-options-file "my_application/my_gitlab_demo_options.txt" cmake --build "build" --clean-first
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - my_application/
    expire_in: 1 days


project_analysis_phase_2:
  stage: project_analysis
  tags:
    - myapp
  script:
    - ls
    #- cd my_application <= Error occurs here
  dependencies:
    - project_analysis_phase_1
```

Error occurs saying "my_application" does not exist. I did a little debugging on each Jobs and here what I found:

1. After the Job "project_build" -> build/ artifact is created and I could see it on GitLab, also running the Job locally on VSC with GirLab extension and also it includes the right contents
2. At start of Job "project_analysis_phase_1", build artifact is found and thus the script can execute in this Job without errors. At end of this Job, my_application/ artifact is saved (again confirmed on GitLab and on VSC)
3. Problem occurs when 3rd job "project_analysis_phase_2" starts. Both build/ and my_appliction/ artifacts are cleared and `ls` command confirms the same.

What am I doing wrong? My understanding is that once artifact is created, it is not cleared before another Job starts (unless there is a way to do it) and any stage/job can reuse the artifact created. Is my understanding wrong or my script is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default artifacts are all passed to other jobs without using dependencies keyword. Maybe try removing that and see if you can see the artifacts that you are looking for.

Have a look at the gitlab docs - hope it helps :)
[gitlab dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies)